# Aligning decimal points - how to use siunitx or dcolumn with tabulary?

Tags: siunitx, sublime-text, tabulary, dcolumn

I've been trying to understand the syntax for `siunitx` and how to make it work with `tabulary` to align data around decimals with appropriate significant figures in columns. Does one need to manually adjust the `S[table-format... ]` for every column? Is there a universal setting for an entire table?
I intend to create longer tables (probably with `longtable`?) which will spread across multiple pages of the document and adjusting this for every column would be too much.

Could I get help adjusting the MWE for decimal alignment please?
Also how can I increase padding on the single row on the bottom? I tried changing `{l}` to `{lb}` in the `\multicolumn{12}{l}{..text..} \\` string, what argument must I pass?

Here's what Im working with (perhaps worth noting I'm working with a custom thesis document class with multiple nested files so preamble isn't that simple).

Thanks

[image]

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs, array, tabularx, ragged2e, tabulary,longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{XRF and ICP-AES standardisation, Bureau Veritas Canada (BVC) data}
        \label{AppB-XRF-ICP-BVC}
    %\resizebox{\pagewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LCRRRRRRCCCC}
        \toprule
        Analyte & MDL & SO-19 Expected & SO-19(1) & SO-19(2) & SO-19(3) & SO-19(4) & AVG SO-19 & Accuracy (absolute) & Error (± \% relative to SO-19) & 2$\sigma$ & RSD (\%) \\ \midrule
        MAX &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.89 & 2.54\% &  & 2.55 \\ 
        AVG &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.13 & 1.14\% &  & 0.57 \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{\textit{Major elements (wt\%)}} \\
        \ce{SiO2} & 0.01 & 61.13 & 60.19 & 60.36 & 60.23 & 60.18 & 60.24 & 0.89 & 1.46 & 0.17 & 0.14 \\ 
        \ce{Al2O3} & 0.01 & 13.95 & 14.04 & 14.05 & 14.07 & 14.13 & 14.07 & 0.12 & 0.88 & 0.08 & 0.29 \\ 
        \ce{Fe2O3} & 0.04 & 7.47 & 7.57 & 7.43 & 7.57 & 7.54 & 7.53 & 0.06 & 0.77 & 0.13 & 0.88 \\ 
        CaO & 0.01 & 6 & 5.95 & 5.95 & 5.94 & 5.94 & 5.95 & 0.05 & 0.92& 0.01 & 0.10 \\ 
        MgO & 0.01 & 2.88 & 2.95 & 2.95 & 2.93 & 2.94 & 2.94 & 0.06 & 2.17 & 0.02 & 0.33 \\ 
        \ce{Na2O} & 0.01 & 4.11 & 4.07 & 4.06 & 4.04 & 4.05 & 4.06 & 0.06 & 1.34 & 0.03 & 0.32 \\ 
        \ce{K2O} & 0.01 & 1.29 & 1.31 & 1.31 & 1.3 & 1.31 & 1.31 & 0.02 & 1.36 & 0.01 & 0.38 \\ 
        \ce{Cr2O3} & - & 0.5 & 0.506 & 0.501 & 0.507 & 0.511 & 0.51 & 0.01 & 1.25 & - & 0.81 \\ 
        \ce{TiO2} & 0.01 & 0.69 & 0.71 & 0.71 & 0.71 & 0.7 & 0.71 & 0.02 & 2.54 & 0.01 & 0.71 \\
        MnO & 0.01 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0 & 0.00 \\ 
        \ce{P2O5} & 0.01 & 0.32 & 0.32 & 0.31 & 0.32 & 0.33 & 0.32 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 2.55 \\ 
        LOI & -5.1 &  & 1.9 & 1.9 & 1.9 & 1.9 & 1.9 &  &  &  &  \\ 
        Total & - &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{\textit{Trace elements (ppm)}} \\
        Ba & 5 & 486 & 466 & 461 & 472 & 473 & 468 & 18.00 & 3.70 & 11.20 & 1.20 \\ 
        Nb & 5 & 68.5 & 80 & 74 & 71 & 74 & 74.75 & 6.25 & 9.12 & 7.55 & 5.05 \\ 
        Ni & 20 & 470 & 476 & 466 & 467 & 476 & 471.25 & 1.25 & 0.27 & 11.00 & 1.17 \\ 
        Sc & 1 & 27 & 26 & 26 & 26 & 27 & 26.25 & 0.75 & 2.78 & 1.00 & 1.90 \\ 
        Sr & 2 & 317.1 & 316 & 317 & 314 & 315 & 315.5 & 1.60 & 0.35 & 2.58 & 0.41 \\ 
        Y & 3 & 35.5 & 35 & 34 & 35 & 35 & 34.75 & 0.75 & 1.41 & 1.00 & 1.44 \\ 
        Zr & 5 & 112 & 121 & 123 & 118 & 115 & 119.25 & 7.25 & 8.04 & 7.00 & 2.94 \\ 
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{MDL = method detection limit, AVG = average, RSD = relative standard deviation, na = not analysed} \\
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A place to start from:

[image]

Depending on the settings of your actual document (font size, margin widths, ...) some adjustments may be needed in order to make sure the table fits into the available space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{XRF and ICP-AES standardisation, Bureau Veritas Canada (BVC) data}
        \label{AppB-XRF-ICP-BVC}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=-2.2]
                                     *{6}{S[table-format=3.3]}
                                     *{4}{S[table-format=2.3]}}
        \toprule
        Analyte & {MDL} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{SO-19} & {Accur.} & {Error\textsuperscript{*}} & {2$\sigma$} & {RSD} \\ \cmidrule{3-8}
        & & {Exp.} & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {AVG} & {(abs.)} &  &  & {(\%)} \\ \midrule
        MAX &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.89 & {2.54\%} &  & 2.55 \\ 
        AVG &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.13 & {1.14\%} &  & 0.57 \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\textit{Major elements (wt\%)}} \\
        \ce{SiO2} & 0.01 & 61.13 & 60.19 & 60.36 & 60.23 & 60.18 & 60.24 & 0.89 & 1.46 & 0.17 & 0.14 \\ 
        \ce{Al2O3} & 0.01 & 13.95 & 14.04 & 14.05 & 14.07 & 14.13 & 14.07 & 0.12 & 0.88 & 0.08 & 0.29 \\ 
        \ce{Fe2O3} & 0.04 & 7.47 & 7.57 & 7.43 & 7.57 & 7.54 & 7.53 & 0.06 & 0.77 & 0.13 & 0.88 \\ 
        CaO & 0.01 & 6 & 5.95 & 5.95 & 5.94 & 5.94 & 5.95 & 0.05 & 0.92& 0.01 & 0.10 \\ 
        MgO & 0.01 & 2.88 & 2.95 & 2.95 & 2.93 & 2.94 & 2.94 & 0.06 & 2.17 & 0.02 & 0.33 \\ 
        \ce{Na2O} & 0.01 & 4.11 & 4.07 & 4.06 & 4.04 & 4.05 & 4.06 & 0.06 & 1.34 & 0.03 & 0.32 \\ 
        \ce{K2O} & 0.01 & 1.29 & 1.31 & 1.31 & 1.3 & 1.31 & 1.31 & 0.02 & 1.36 & 0.01 & 0.38 \\ 
        \ce{Cr2O3} & {--} & 0.5 & 0.506 & 0.501 & 0.507 & 0.511 & 0.51 & 0.01 & 1.25 & {--} & 0.81 \\ 
        \ce{TiO2} & 0.01 & 0.69 & 0.71 & 0.71 & 0.71 & 0.7 & 0.71 & 0.02 & 2.54 & 0.01 & 0.71 \\
        MnO & 0.01 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0 & 0.00 \\ 
        \ce{P2O5} & 0.01 & 0.32 & 0.32 & 0.31 & 0.32 & 0.33 & 0.32 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 2.55 \\ 
        LOI & -5.1 &  & 1.9 & 1.9 & 1.9 & 1.9 & 1.9 &  &  &  &  \\ 
        Total & {--} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\textit{Trace elements (ppm)}} \\
        Ba & 5 & 486 & 466 & 461 & 472 & 473 & 468 & 18.00 & 3.70 & 11.20 & 1.20 \\ 
        Nb & 5 & 68.5 & 80 & 74 & 71 & 74 & 74.75 & 6.25 & 9.12 & 7.55 & 5.05 \\ 
        Ni & 20 & 470 & 476 & 466 & 467 & 476 & 471.25 & 1.25 & 0.27 & 11.00 & 1.17 \\ 
        Sc & 1 & 27 & 26 & 26 & 26 & 27 & 26.25 & 0.75 & 2.78 & 1.00 & 1.90 \\ 
        Sr & 2 & 317.1 & 316 & 317 & 314 & 315 & 315.5 & 1.60 & 0.35 & 2.58 & 0.41 \\ 
        Y & 3 & 35.5 & 35 & 34 & 35 & 35 & 34.75 & 0.75 & 1.41 & 1.00 & 1.44 \\ 
        Zr & 5 & 112 & 121 & 123 & 118 & 115 & 119.25 & 7.25 & 8.04 & 7.00 & 2.94 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
    \item[]MDL = method detection limit, AVG = average, RSD = relative standard deviation, na = not analysed, Accur. = Accuracy, abs. = absolute, Exp. = Expected, \textsuperscript{*} (± \% relative to SO-19)
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Some background explanation on

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     S[table-format=-2.2]
                                     *{6}{S[table-format=3.3]}
                                     *{4}{S[table-format=2.3]}}
```

The first argument (`{\linewidth}`) is the overall width of the table, the second argument contains the column specifiers. The first column is an `l` type colum. `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` is added to make sure the table fits into the textwidth (Simplified, it evenly distributes extra horizontal white space between the columns.) The following three lines contain the column specifiers for the other 11 columns of the table. `*{4}{S[table-format=2.3]}` is identical to `S[table-format=2.3] S[table-format=2.3] S[table-format=2.3] S[table-format=2.3]` and was used since you mentioned wanting a more univeral setting that applied to the entire table. While one could also use `\sisetup{table-format:=...}` after `\begin{table}` and before `tabular*` in order to apply the settings to all `S` type columns in this particular tabular, your table needs different `table-format` options depending on the contents of the individual columns.

Comment: This looks lovely, thanks, but I'd like to have a better idea of the syntax, particularly the bits after `\begin{tabular*}` is called. Could you break this - `{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} S[table-format=-2.2]
*{6}{S[table-format=3.3]}
*{4}{S[table-format=2.3]}}` down a bit for me?
Also 1) why is `threeparttable` preferred here?; 2) does `tablenotes` work with all tabulation environments?

Comment: @Wolfe79: I just edited my answer to include some background info on the `\begin{tabular*}...` part. I hope this helps. Regarding the other questions: 1) I decided to use the `threeparttable` package for the text below the table since you mentioned wanting to " increase padding on the single row on the bottom". 2): `tablenotes` form the `threeparttable` package also works with environments such as `tabular` and `tabularx`, but it does not work with environments that allow  a table to occupy multiple pages such as `longtable`, `xltabular`,... For them use the `threeparttablex` package instead.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!